# Using Gson to Parse JSonObject to Model

Tags: java, android, gson

I have the following model:
I am trying to parse the response from the server using GSon, with the following code:

```
   public class UserDetails
    {
      private final int ID;
      private final String user_email;

      public UserDetails(int ID, String user_email)
     {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.user_email = user_email;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getUser_email()
    {
        return user_email;
    }

   }


   public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
       String mMessage = response.body().string();
       if (response.isSuccessful()) {
         try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            UserDetails user_details = gson.fromJson(mMessage, UserDetails.class);
            Log.d("Success","The response from the server" + " " + user_details.getID() 
               + " " + user_details.getUser_email().toString());
            Log.d("Success", " "+mMessage);
         }
       }
   }
```

However, when i place a break point to obtain the user details the values are always displayed as null.

Comment: Good first question buddy. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a non default constructor, and you don't seem to have a no arguments (default) constructor, as per the [docs](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson):

Please add one to your pojo:

```
 public UserDetails()
 {

}
```

If you want to be sure your POJO is well structured use this [site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). It will generate the pojos based on your json structure.

This is roughly how it should look like:

```
public class UserDetail {

@SerializedName("ID")
@Expose
private Integer iD;
@SerializedName("user_email")
@Expose
private String userEmail;

public Integer getID() {
return iD;
}

public void setID(Integer iD) {
this.iD = iD;
}

public String getUserEmail() {
return userEmail;
}

public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
this.userEmail = userEmail;
}

}
```

Comment: That is what the return JSON is when I use PostMan {"UserDetails":[{"ID":132,"user_email":"tungamiraimujuru+11@gmail.com"}]}

Comment: did you try adding the empty constructor?

Comment: Yes I have added the empty constructor

Comment: Yes your solution worked. I cannot upvote I have no reputation

Comment: @George Mark it as Accepted Answer, The empty tick under the voting number, Make it Green